# Need to translate words in .ts file of angular-7 application for localization of app

Tags: angular, localization, angular7, code-translation, ngx-translate

I have to localize the angular-7 application. For that we already created the localizationModule which impports all required dependencies from `'@ngx-translate/core';`. Also I have imported the `userService` in which selected language will be set for application translation.
I have translated all the `html` pages but the messages which are written in `.ts` file needs to be converted.
I am not getting any way to achieve this.
Can anyone help me to get out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `TranslateService` from  `@ngx-translate/core`.
You have two ways:

- `translate.instant` with would just translate the word to the defined language directly.
- `translate.get` which get the value from an observable.

Here a little example how to use it:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

yourTranslatedText : string;
yourTranslatedObservableText : string;

constructor(
  private translateService: TranslateService,
) {
   yourTranslatedText = this.translateService.instant('your.key.string'); 
   this.translateService.get('your.key.string').subscribe((translatedString) => {
      yourTranslatedObservableText = translatedString;
   });
}
```

Note that you can pass an **Array** of keys so you can translate all the words you want at once.

Comment: `this.toastCtrl.errorToast("Please upload pdf file");` this text I have to modify. You mean I need to create the variable with this String in french json file like,  `"cartComponent":{"toaster":"Étiquette d'expédition téléchargée avec succès."}` and then access it from .ts file like,  `let msg =this.translateService.instant( toaster);`      but its not working..

Comment: If you have translated the `html`, you know that you have the keys like : 'cartComponent.toaster'. That's the key you have to use in the translateService. For example:  `let msg =this.translateService.instant('cartComponent.toaster');` (Note that It is a string)

Comment: Yes, you have to add the "Please upload pdf file" to the json file, and then use the key in the translateService.

Comment: Hey.. daniel...now I am facing issue like, when I logged-in html loaded in selected language, but when I refreshed the page everything changes to English rather that selected language. Can you help me?

Comment: Probably the `this.translateService.instant` is being called **before** you change the language with the `this.translateService.use(lang)`. That's one of the reasons that using the `translateService.get` it's a bit better, it resolves to the actual language no matter when you change the language..

Comment: In every angular component, I need to use this syntax `this.translateService.use(lang)`, that's what you are saying?

Comment: No, that in your code you should do the **this.translateService.use** before everything. (like a service that goes before `ngOnInit()`  and just one service, not in every component) or use the `translateService.get()` solution

Comment: How can we pass they array of keys ? How will I use those keys in different places then ?